# Is there any way to mix or inherit annotation value in Java?

Tags: java, annotations, java-7

I have an annotation like this

```
public @interface anno{
    String a1() default "defaultValueA1";
    String a2() default "defaultValueA2";
    String a3() default "defaultValueA3"
}



Class SuperClass{
    @anno(a1="myA1", a3="myA3")
    private String field1; 
}

Class SubClass extends SuperClass(){
    @anno(a2="myA2", a3="defaultValueA3")
    private String field1;
}
```

currently when I try to get annotaion from subclass, the anno only contains customized a2, but a1 is only able to get default value, is there any way get an annotation mix all superclass specified fields like `{a1:myA1, a2:myA2, a3:defaultValueA3}` but not `{a1:defaultValueA1,a2:myA2, a3:defaultValueA3}`?

---

update:

I know annotation is not inheritable, so I tried mix subClass annotation `{a1:defaultValueA1, a2:myA2, a3:defaultValueA3}` and superClass annotaion `{a1:myA1, a2: defalutValueA2, a3:myA3}`, my way is get all subClass customized values and copy them to superClass annotation, but the problem is when I get all annotation value from subClass, I can't distiguish which value is user defined and which value is come from default value, anyone have suggestion?

```
private void mixAnnotaiont(Annotation target, Annotation source){
    Method[] methods = source.annotationType().getMethods();
    Map<String, Object> sourceCfg = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(source);
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {

         // skip default value, but it's incorrect, user may specify default value in subClass to overwrite superClass value
        Object defaultValue = methods[i].getDefaultValue();
        String name = methods[i].getName();
        if(sourceCfg.get(name).equals(defaultValue)){
            ignoreProperties.add(name);
        }

    }
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target, ignoreProperties.toArray(new String[] {}));
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations aren't inherited according to JavaDoc:

> Open Declaration Annotation[] java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations()
>
> Returns all annotations that are directly present on this element.
>   Unlike the other methods in this interface, this method ignores
>   inherited annotations. (Returns an array of length zero if no
>   annotations are directly present on this element.) The caller of this
>   method is free to modify the returned array; it will have no effect on
>   the arrays returned to other callers.

But you can try have a while loop and get all the declared annotations using this method
java.lang.Class.getSuperclass()

```
while(loop thru the super class)
{
   // get declared annotation
}
```

Comment: Thanks. ya, i can get all annotations from retrieve all superclass, but stuck at how to mix them... I updated questions added my problem while try to mix all annotations.

Comment: Ok, as you know the annotations are resolved at compile time and the values of its attributes will remain constant during runtime. 

Then you know what will be the default value of attributes. You can check the value when you get the attributes from subClasses to identify if its user defined or default. 

Or you can store the attribute values from SuperClass and compare with every value pulled from subClass to know if its user defined.

Comment: Thanks. But I still got problem, if i got a value from subClass, if the value is different with superclass and defaultValue, then i can simply overrite supervalue, but if the subclass's value is different with superClass but same as defaultValue, then i dun know should i overrite, in this case, the subclass's value may come from defaultValue or just user set it(same as defaultValue). Sorry, it might a bit complex, my example in the question may state it clearer then here.

Comment: Ok, another thought, why don't you remove the default values from annotation and set them to empty ""(which can be treated as "no value"). This would help you track who has set the value (Sub or Super) And at the end of your computation use default if nothing is set by Sub or Super (In case if required).

Comment: But if no default value, then user have to set every annotation field manually in every class field, bad experience....

Comment: That's why i said default as ""... So that user needn't specify every value.

Comment: then you can accept the answer if you found our discussion helpful to you :)

Comment: really thanks for the discussion, but actually there is no answer yet for my qustion, so I might mislead other readers if accpet your answer. :( sorry and thanks again.

Comment: If you are still finding answer, it would be better to refine your question and let the forum know where have you reached and what's the current issue. Otherwise it will be ignored. ( letting you know to help you get answer)